# Can I assume the absolute GPS positioning error doesn't change much within a certain timeframe?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, gps

There's an idea for a small tool going round in my head. It would, amongst other stuff, require measuring the distance the users device has moved. This is going to be an iPhone App, however the question applies to all sorts of GPS enabled devices I guess.

I don't need the direction, speed or exact positions, just the scalar distance. The thing is, the distances to be measured are rather small in terms of GPS precision - propably like 20 to 30 meters. With an average iPhone GPS CEP of 10 meters, this would mean the measured distance could in the worst case end up anywhere between 0 and 40 meters.

Now I'm wondering - since I don't need absolute positions, is it safe to assume the offset imposed by the position error will not change significantly if the timeframe is sufficiently small?

Say the user moves the device 30 meters in 30 seconds, going straight from position A to position B - can I assume that the absolute error has shifted only slightly and thus my relative precision to be better than the  absolute precision as reported by the device?

Comment: If you want to approxmate your position there is algorithm that can help you. In robot Kalman filter are often used, but its not easy project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience doing lots of gecaching with a dedicated gps device is that you can't make that assumption.  The position will bounce all around within 10 meters or so all the time. So you can see lots of movement even when the person is standing still.

I don't have an iPhone but I doubt it is better than a purpose built GPS receiver.

Comment: You're propably right, maybe the error does in fact "move" too quickly. I should have thought of that myself since I'm into geocaching, too. However I blamed jumping coordinates on my moving back and forth and poor receiption between buildings :) Besides, my 60csx is not as prone to jumping as my iPhone is. Well, I'll propably end up testing and providing an input means for the user to manually enter a distance. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

I would say the best way to get the answer would be to do some tests on your own (assuming you have an iPhone).

Also, you can integrate over the output of the accelerometers and end up with delta position.  That will accumulate error, but I'm not sure how quickly.

Comment: Using the accelerometers is an interesting idea. You could pretty much tell when the person isn't moving. But I'm not sure how that will help tell which of the many readings you get that are +-10 meters is the "Correct" one.

Comment: I think you missed my point.  An accelerometer tells you the acceleration.  If you integrate that, you get velocity.  If you integrate that, you get position (relative to where you started).  You don't need GPS data at all for that to work.

Comment: I'll in fact propably end up doing some tests - this should be a matter of an hour. As for the accelerometers, I think the double integration would lead to errors of at least the same magnitude compared to GPS. However CLLocationManager allows for an accuracy mode (..BestForNavigation) which in fact incorporates additional sensor data. Maybe this will do it for me...